# Method to draw a path throws error when invoked

Tags: java, android, canvas, arraylist, path

I have an arraylist of points which are drawn onto a canvas. I have made a method (drawLine) which draws a path/line from one point to another according to the points the user clicks on.

The order in which the points are clicked are put into an arraylist called userPath.

The drawLine method then captures the last two values of userPath and stores them in another arraylist called realPath, and draws a line between these two points and can be seen below.

```
//this class draws a line
public void drawLine(float x, float y)
{
    mPath.reset();
    if (userPath.size()>=2);
    {
        realPath.add(userPath.get(userPath.size()-1));
        realPath.add(userPath.get(userPath.size()-2));
    }

    // start point
    Point p = realPath.get(mLastPointIndex);

    mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
    // end point
    p = realPath.get(mLastPointIndex + 1);
    //this goes through every point in realPath array list
    mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    mPath.reset();

    ++mLastPointIndex;
    isPathStarted = false;
}
```

When I call the method (drawLine(x,y)) however, it throws an error.

```
 switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

              // this will draw the path
              //mContext = this.mContext;
              float Cox = event.getX();
              float Coy = event.getY();

              double CoX = (double) Cox;
              double CoY = (double) Coy;
              //the euclid method only accepts double numbers therefore the coordinates of the
              //points the user is clicking on need to be converted from float to double

              Double NearestDistance = 1000.12; //this is hardcoded for the sake of declaring the variable.
              Point NearestPoint = null;

              for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.size(); i++)
              {
                  Point current = mPoints.get(i);
                  double xi = current.x;
                  double yi = current.y;

                  double dis = Euclid(CoX, CoY, xi, yi);

                  if (dis < NearestDistance)
                  {
                      NearestPoint = current;
                      NearestDistance = dis;
                  }
              }

              String text = "the closest point to where you clicked is: " + NearestPoint + " and the coordinates are: " + NearestPoint.x + ", "+ NearestPoint.y;
              Toast.makeText(mContext, text, LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              if (userPath.contains(NearestPoint))
              {
                  String pickPoint = "Pick another point";
                  Toast.makeText(mContext, pickPoint, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              else
              {
                  userPath.add(NearestPoint);
                  Toast.makeText(mContext, userPath + "", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  drawLine(x,y);
                  //need to call the drawLine method here to draw the line between the last 2 elements in the arraylist. this throws an error!!!
              }

              invalidate();
              break;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: What error? in what line?

Comment: drawLine(x,y); 
                  //need to call the drawLine method here to draw the line between the last 2 elements in the arraylist. this throws an error!!! 
The error is that 'x and y cannot be resolved'

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking for the trace of the error. It's really difficult to guess what the problem is without the stack trace of the error

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do a stack trace of the error. all i know is when I invoke the method it doesn't allow me to pass the variables x and y.

Comment: The trace of the error is the message that you get when you run your code. I assume that your code does not even compile. How are you defining and assigning the variables x and y that you pass to your drawLine function? Have  you tried changing drawLine(x,y); for drawLine(NearestPoint.x,NearestPoint.y);?

Comment: I have tried that. At first I thought it was because NearestPoint is a double and the drawLine method passes its variables as a float. That still didn't work.

Comment: the variables are defined in the drawLine method as below:
public void drawLine(double x, double y)
    {
    
        if (isPathStarted)
        {
            if (userPath.size() >= 2) ;
            {
                realPath.add(userPath.get(userPath.size() - 1));
                realPath.add(userPath.get(userPath.size() - 2));
 Point p = realPath.get(mLastPointIndex);
 mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            
             p = realPath.get(mLastPointIndex + 1);
   
             mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
             mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
             mPath.reset();